# Как изменить путь запроса (перенаправить на контроллер) в ASP.NET WebApi используя DelegatingHandler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

На мой ASP.NET WebApi (.NET 7) поступают GET-запросы. Мне обходимо изменить URI запроса, чтобы перенаправлять их на разные контроллеры в зависимости от значения параметры Query.

На данный момент я пытаюсь просто перенаправить запрос без проверки параметра. Для этого использую DelegatingHandler. Когда я отправляю запрос с путем совпадающим с маршрутом самого контроллера все проходит нормально и контроллер получает управление. Однако, когда путь не соответствует заданному маршруту, запрос просто сбрасывается.

Вот как выглядит мой DelegatingHandler:

```
public sealed class SpecificDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public SpecificDelegatingHandler()
    {
        InnerHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    }


    public async Task Test(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        await SendAsync(request, new CancellationToken(false));
    }


    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var leftPart = new Uri(request.RequestUri?.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority));
            
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(leftPart, "/api/firmware");

        return await base.SendAsync(request, new CancellationToken(true));
    }
}
```

Вот так выглядит обертка:

```
public class SpecificDelegatingHandlerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _nextDelegate;

    private readonly SpecificDelegatingHandler _delegatingHandler;



    public SpecificDelegatingHandlerMiddleware(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider p, RequestDelegate nextDelegate, SpecificDelegatingHandler delegatingHandler)
    {
        _nextDelegate = nextDelegate;
        _delegatingHandler = delegatingHandler;
    }


    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var task = _delegatingHandler.Test(httpRequestMessage);
        await _nextDelegate.Invoke(context);
    } // При правильном пути в исходном запросе здесь управление передается контроллеру. При неправильном просто сбрасывается без всяких исключений.
}
```

Добавление сервисов:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<SpecificDelegatingHandler>();
...
app.UseMiddleware<SpecificDelegatingHandlerMiddleware>();
...
app.MapControllers();
```

Мой контроллер:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/firmware")]
public class FirmwareController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(new { Debug = "controller works!" });
    }
}
```